# Multiple Window Problems - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am have trouble using multiple windows in WPF and switching between them using a button. In theory my application should have 2 buttons, one forward and one back each on respectively changing the window to the previous and next window.

Unfortunately I get a Stackoverflow error, through my research I feel that it has something to do with me creating new windows that are creating the window again when the previous window is created, thus making a horrible loop. However I don't know where I can put the window creation code to stop this problem or if there are other ways to fix this.

Here is code for my windows:

First Window

```
public partial class Presenation_1 : Window
{
    Presentation_2 p2 = new Presentation_2();
    MainWindow M = new MainWindow();

    public Presenation_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        p2.Show();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        M.Show();
    }
}
```

Second Window

```
public partial class Presentation_2 : Window
{
    Presentation_3 p3 = new Presentation_3();
    Presenation_1 p1 = new Presenation_1();
    public Presentation_2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        p3.Show();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        p1.Show();
    }
}
```

Third Window

```
public partial class Presentation_3 : Window
{
    Presentation_4 p4 = new Presentation_4();
    Presentation_2 p2 = new Presentation_2();

    public Presentation_3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        p4.Show();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        p2.Show();
    }
}
```

Fourth Window

```
public partial class Presentation_4 : Window
{
    Presentation_3 p3 = new Presentation_3();
    MainWindow M = new MainWindow();

    public Presentation_4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        M.Show();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        p3.Show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use built-in navigation framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create your Windows before the button is clicked, you can create them in the event handler:

```
private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var p2 = new Presentation_2();
    this.Close();
    p2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you this appeared to work fine, I don't know why I didn't think of creating it here.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a windows, you create 2 other windows with

```
new Presentation_X()
```

This new windows is automaticaly show and itself open 2 other windows.

You can create this windows once in the Mainwindow (auto hide this one), pass the reference in constructor and not close these windows. Quick example (not tested) :

```
public partial class Presenation_X : Window
{
    private Window preview;
    private Window next;

    public Presenation_X(Window w1, Window w2)
    {
        this.preview = w1;
        this.next = w2;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.next.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.preview.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```