# Hide and show multiple WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, show-hide

I have three windows, a start window, a window with a overview and a window with details

When I open my window with overview, the start window has to hide, when I open the details from the overview, the overview has to hide and when i close the details only the overview may become visible again.

this is what I use to hide the window

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
_frmDetail.showDialog();
this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

but when I do it like this, not only my overview, become visible when i close details but also my startscreen and i only want to show it when my overview close

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497427/multiple-window-problems-c-sharp-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a strange and potentially annoying (for the users) application requirement that you are asking about here. It is much more common to display different views in one `Window`, rather than displaying different `Window`s, but you're still entitled to do that.

You basically need a parent class, maybe `MainWindow.xaml.cs`? This class can hold references to the three `Window`s and be in charge of opening and closing, or hiding and showing them. You could have a method something like this to open/show a new `Window` and hide the others:

```
private void DisplayWindow(Window windowToShow)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().
Where(w => w.IsVisible).Count(); i++)
    {
        Window windowToHide = Application.Current.Windows[i];
        windowToHide.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    windowToShow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Then whenever you need to show a new `Window`, you can just call it like this:

```
DisplayWindow(_frmDetail);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set the visibility to collapsed, then show a dialog, then set the visibility again ... 
I'm not too sure what you're doing, nor what you're calling a `window`.

In any case, an easy solution can be having 3 items overlaid on top each other (in the same grid for example), and setting their visibility to properties, like : `ShowMain`, `ShowOverview` and `ShowDetails`.

Now, whenever you need one, set that property to Visible, and the other 2 to Collapsed, and your problem is solved (these are all in the same window really).

Answer (score 0):

Minimize it and set `ShowInTaskbar` to false.

```
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better solution. You access the object directly:

```
private PlaceholderEditorWindow _myWindow;

private void ShowWindow()
{
    if (_myWindow == null)
    {
        _myWindow = new MyWindow();
        _myWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        _myWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Dont close the window, instead use this (in the Window class):

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
```